# How to merge different excel sheets in R without any common column?

Tags: r, excel

I know how to combine data frames using merge function. I also tried importing excel sheets in different data frames but I am not able to merge since it doesn't have common columns. If you provide code in example, please be specific with only code related to excel sheets (merging excel sheets without common column and creating only a single excel sheet)

After importing excel sheet, I tried importing sheets one by one in data frame but the question is how to merge these three and make one since it doesn't have common column.

```
x1 <- data.frame(read_excel("Retail Data.xlsx", sheet=1))

x2 <- data.frame(read_excel("Retail Data.xlsx", sheet=2))

x3 <- data.frame(read_excel("Retail Data.xlsx", sheet=3))
```

And if I do:

Customer_Final <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3)

shows error: Error in data.frame(x1, x2, x3)

Comment: when I try cbind it says error:Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :

Comment: Ryan, I want to merge all the sheets in a singe excel sheet with base merge() and dplyr function as well if that may work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve]!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your data.frames have different amount of rows. You need to adjust their lenghts and bind them column-wise.

```
library(readxl)
library(XLConnect)
# Create reproducible data
library(XLConnect)
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:26, b = letters[1:26])
df2 <- data.frame(a = 1:16, b = letters[1:16])
df3 <- data.frame(a = 1:6, b = letters[1:6])

# Save to xlsx-file
wb <- loadWorkbook("Retail Data.xlsx", create = TRUE)
createSheet(wb, "sh1")
createSheet(wb, "sh2")
createSheet(wb, "sh3")
writeWorksheet(wb, df1, "sh1")
writeWorksheet(wb, df2, "sh2")
writeWorksheet(wb, df3, "sh3")
saveWorkbook(wb)

# load sheets
x1 <- data.frame(read_excel("Retail Data.xlsx", sheet=1))
x2 <- data.frame(read_excel("Retail Data.xlsx", sheet=2))
x3 <- data.frame(read_excel("Retail Data.xlsx", sheet=3))
max_rows <- max(nrow(x1), nrow(x2), nrow(x3))

# fill missing columns w/NAs
x1s <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = ncol(x1), nrow = max_rows - nrow(x1))), names(x1))
x1d <- rbind(x1, x1s)
x2s <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = ncol(x2), nrow = max_rows - nrow(x2))), names(x2))
x2d <- rbind(x2, x2s)
x3s <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = ncol(x3), nrow = max_rows - nrow(x3))), names(x3))
x3d <- rbind(x3, x3s)

# Combine column-wise
y <- cbind(x1d, x2d, x3d)
y
```